# How to check for windows 11 compatibility on Ubuntu

Tags: operating-system, ubuntu-20.04, tpm

My pc **Asus X550V** is running Ubuntu 20 LTS and i want to switch to Windows 11

How to check for the TPM 2.0 chipset is present on my pc or not

PC Specs:

- i5-6300HQ
- GTX 950M
- 8GB ram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, I5-6300HQ will not be supported by windows 11. My PC is Dell E5470 with I5-6300HQ but still appear this error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HuTI.png)